# Excel 2016 Change grading criteria based on rank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula, rank

Edit: I consider this solved now.
You guys are geniuses (at least for me :) )
I applied Solar Mike's solution to my actual Excel data (the one here is a simplified version) and it worked!
Thank you so much and I send you some virtual beers!

Please help me come up with a grading formula for the following situation.
I have the following simplified situation:

All students in my class are pre-assigned one of 3 Ranks: A, B, C.

All 3 ranks have different grading criteria:

Rank A:

90 and higher: X

80 to 89: Y

79 and lower: Z

Rank B:

80 and higher: X

70 to 79: Y

69 and lower: Z

Rank C:

70 and higher: X

60 to 69: Y

59 and lower: Z

So when I input the student's score in Excel, I would like to get their grade (X,Y,or Z) based on their rank. 
Please take a look at the attached screenshot. I would like to get the student's grade in column D based on the values of columns B and C (the current values in column D are manually input. Please help me make a formula to get them automatically). 
The criteria are in cells B6:D15.

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with index() and match(), have a look at this:

[image]

Formula in cell D3 dragged down is:

```
IF(C3="","",INDEX($I$4:$K$8,MATCH(C3,$H$4:$H$8,1),MATCH(B3,$I$3:$K$3,0)))
```

The if() is to put a blank when the score is blank.

Comment: @JvdV thanks for the reminder, I was actually not aware I had to do this. Now it is done. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

In `D2` put:

```
=MID("ZYX",MATCH(C2,CHOOSE(CODE(B2)-64,{1,80,90},{1,70,80},{1,60,70})),1)
```

No need for a lookup-table in this case. Change ranges in the arrays if need be. For clarification:

- `=MID("ZYX",<Step2>, 1)` - A substring of lenght 1 from `ZYX` through `MID`.
- `MATCH(C2,<Step3>)` - Return position of element in array that is `>=` to `C2`.
- `CHOOSE(CODE(B2)-64,{1,80,90},{1,70,80},{1,60,70})` - Returns the appropriate array to choose from in step 2 based on `B2`.

Step through the formula evaluation to see it done step-by-step.

[image]

---

<sup>***Note:*** If you are unsure if both lower- and uppercases can be used then just include an `UPPER(B2)` instead of a `B2` reference.</sup>

Comment: A table can make the decisions and any changes easier to see.

Comment: For some @SolarMike. To me the formula is quite clear. But yes, if OP intends to step away from the provided data then your `INDEX` way is fine, i'll credit you for that.

Answer (score 0):

As per OP's layout, try to use `IMAGINARY` function as in.

In `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=INDEX({"X";"Y";"Z"},MATCH(C2,INDEX(-IMAGINARY(OFFSET($C$6,MATCH(B2,B$7:B$15,0),0,3)&"i"),0),-1))
```

[image]